# insert into select with union needs derived table

Tags: mysql

Why do I need to do another select when I am trying to insert distinct values into a table? Also: is there a better way to do this?

WORKS:

```
INSERT INTO phppos_categories (name) 
SELECT category FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT category FROM phppos_items as items 
    UNION 
    SELECT DISTINCT category FROM phppos_item_kits as item_kits) 
as category_result;
```

DOESN'T WORK:

```
INSERT INTO phppos_categories (name) 
    (SELECT DISTINCT category FROM phppos_items as items 
    UNION 
    SELECT DISTINCT category FROM phppos_item_kits as item_kits)
```

Comment: have you tried removing the parentheses from the 2nd query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this it will work

```
INSERT INTO phppos_categories (name) 
SELECT DISTINCT category FROM phppos_items 
UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT category FROM phppos_item_kits
```

Comment: This works; but I don't understand why () make all the difference.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because the syntax is defined as `INSERT .. SELECT` i.e. there has to be a valid `SELECT` in the overall statement.  For your "DOESN'T WORK" example, if you comment out the `INSERT` you're left with an invalid statement.  This will not run:

```
--INSERT INTO phppos_categories (name) 
(SELECT DISTINCT category FROM phppos_items as items 
UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT category FROM phppos_item_kits as item_kits)
```

Do the same with the functioning statement and it will still execute.

Is there a better way?  If the two tables' values do not overlap `UNION ALL` will save some processing.  Depending you your rowcounts and skews two separate statements may achieve better overall performance.  You would have to test to find out.

Comment: yes you are right @Michael Green